# How to add page number in a document using Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs

I would like to add page number and total number of pages into the document footer using Google Apps Script.

I can't find the api for it. Is it possible?

Answer (score 6):

As Serge already mentioned, now there is no possibility to insert a page number and/or a page count programmatically from a GAS, but there is a workaround by creating a document, in the Editor, inserting a page number to the footer by clicking the `Insert->Page number->Bottom of page` menu item, saving the document and using a copy of this document as a template in the script. The [File.makeCopy](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/class_file#makeCopy) method services to make a copy of the template.

Answer (score 5):

As far as I know there is no way to handle page numbers in GAS, there is an [issue on that subject](http://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=1656&q=page%20numbers&colspec=Stars%20Opened%20ID%20Type%20Status%20Summary%20Component%20Owner), You could star it to keep informed if something changes... and kind of vote for it by the way ;-)

Comment: Serge, the [issue](http://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=1656) is not relevant for the topic starter, because in it only the `paragraph.getPageNumber()` method requested, but the topic starter needs something like 'document.addFooter().appendPageCount()'.

Comment: @megabyte1024 : I agree but the title of the enhancement request in the issue tracker is ' Provide access to page numbering ' which is more a general request to have access to page numbers... so I find it quite relevant in this case :-)

Comment: Do you think the support will fix the issue, basing on the title? :)